# How to put numbers in ascending order in an arraylist in Java?

Tags: java

I have made some code which gets numbers from the standard input and I want to take these values and sort them in ascending order. How do I do it?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean Done = false;
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(20);


        while(Done == false){
            System.out.print("Enter number: ");
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            numbers.add(x);

            System.out.print("Keep going? (Y/N)");
            String keepGoing = sc.next();

            if(keepGoing.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
                ;
            else if(keepGoing.equalsIgnoreCase("N")){
                Done = true;

                                //this is just temporary to print out the numbers.
                                for(int n : numbers){
                    System.out.print(n + " ");
                }
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Command not recognised...");
        }



    }
}
```

Sorry if I am posting a question that has already been answered but I could not find any answers which seemed to work with my code :(

Comment: `Collections.sort(numbers);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collections.sort(numbers);` should do the trick

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, it's a good practice to accept answers if they've helped you ;)

Comment: Oh that's weird... I'm pretty sure last time I tried accepting the answer it said I didn't have a high enough reputation (I'm completely new to Stackoverflow) and it hasn't gone up since... I don't know...

Answer (score 1):

Just [sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) the `ArrayList`:

```
Collections.sort(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean Done = false;
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(20);
        while (Done == false) {
            System.out.print("Enter number: ");
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            numbers.add(x);

            while (true) {
                System.out.print("Keep going? (Y/N) :");
                String keepGoing = sc.next();
                if (keepGoing.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
                    break;
                else if (keepGoing.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                    Done = true;
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("Command not recognised...");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("before sort : " + numbers);
        Collections.sort(numbers);
        System.out.println("after sort : " + numbers);
    }
}
```